# How to add image with Inline Editor on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image: Here is the where am i talking about]I am using Inline Editor in Fulfillment on Dialogflow. I can add response with these codes:

```
    const NEED_QUOTE_INTENT = 'Need Quote'
app.intent(NEED_QUOTE_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const quote_type = conv.parameters[QUOTE_TYPE_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
    if (quote_type == "inspiration") {
            conv.ask("Nice")
    }else if (quote_type == "happiness") {
        conv.ask("Happy")
    }else if (quote_type == "friendship") {
        conv.ask("Friend")
    }else {
        conv.ask("Hello There")
}
})
```

But i can't add image response. I did some research and found people adding with firebase. I want to add image response on this codes. How can i do?

[image: There should be a image]

Comment: Are you doing this using the actions-on-google library or the dialogflow-fulfillment library? (and if you're not sure, can you update the question to include the code where you're doing the `require`?)

Comment: I add on topic a picture where is it.

Comment: const {dialogflow} = require ('actions-on-google') writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using actions-on-google library You can use a [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) to display an image.

Make sure you require Basic Card and Image from the actions-on-google library as below:

```
const {
  dialogflow,
  BasicCard, // important
  Button,
  Image, // important
} = require('actions-on-google');
```

and then use it providing URL of the image you want to display, as below:

```
const NEED_QUOTE_INTENT = 'Need Quote'
app.intent(NEED_QUOTE_INTENT, (conv) => {
    const quote_type = conv.parameters[QUOTE_TYPE_ENTITY].toLowerCase();
    if (quote_type == "inspiration") {
               conv.ask("Nice"); // this Simple Response is necessary
               conv.ask(new BasicCard({
                    image: new Image({
                     url: 'https://example.com/image.png', //url of your image.
                     alt: 'Image alternate text',
                 }),
         }));
    }else if (quote_type == "happiness") {
        conv.ask("Happy")
        //similarly add an image here
    }else if (quote_type == "friendship") {
        conv.ask("Friend")
    }else {
        conv.ask("Hello There")
}
})
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad that helped!

Comment: This worked but i can't view on real devices. Working just on simulator in console.actions.google.com . If you don't mind, can you tell me how can i view on all devices where this application is installed? (Added an image on topic about that)

Answer (score 1):

The actions-on-google library only works on devices that are running the Google Assistant. The responses are for Actions only.

If you also wanted this to work on other platforms that Dialogflow supports, you may want to look into the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library and tailor your response depending on which platform the request comes from.

Comment: I looked that link and i understand some stuff but if you can send me some example about index.js in Inline Editor, i would grateful. Cause my English not really enough to understand like that stuff.